# Flutter: Checking the licenses in platform-tools

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, sdk, android-licenses

When running flutter project, here comes the warning:

```
Checking the license for package SDK Patch Applier v4 in E:\platform-tools_r31.0.3-windows\licenses
Warning: License for package SDK Patch Applier v4 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android Emulator in E:\platform-tools_r31.0.3-windows\licenses
Warning: License for package Android Emulator not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Tools in E:\platform-tools_r31.0.3-windows\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Tools not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 in E:\platform-tools_r31.0.3-windows\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 31 in E:\platform-tools_r31.0.3-windows\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 31 not accepted.
```

But I find that there isn't a package named `E:\platform-tools_r31.0.3-windows\licenses`, just like the picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8msWC.png)

So what could be the problem? And how to solve it? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android SDK path of your flutter project is not defined..

Define it with

`flutter config --android-sdk 'Your SDK Path'`

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. But I used another way, that is creating a folder named licenses in platform-tools, and then copying the licenses in SDK to it. It works.